# Actuate Birt Viewer

Tags: php, reportviewer, birt, viewer, actuate

I have a Birt report which requires a parameter to input.

In my PHP application I have a link to run this report:

```
http://localhost/birt/frameset?__report=test.rptdesign&sample=hello
```

I'm passing the parameter **sample** by URL.

In **Actuate Birt Viewer Toolkit** the report executes fine, but I need to confirm shown variable in input field and press "Finish", then the viewer outputs result.

The question is: How can I run and view the report immediately without any confirmation and pressing "Finish" button in **Actuate Birt Viewer Toolkit**?

For instance previously I have used **BIRT Report Viewer**. There I didn't have such kind of problem. The viewer itself gets any parameters from the URL and executes the report without any user interference.

I just want to achieve the same thing in **Actuate Birt Viewer toolkit**. Your advice would be greatly appreciated since I have failed to find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add __parameterpage=false to your URL the page will not be displayed. [Here](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/viewer-usage.php) is a list of all of the BIRT Viewer Parameters.